# Can't add xaml to project

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

Ive been working with Xamarin Forms Portable projects for a few months now and today i went to create a new project but when I went to add a new Xaml page, the "Add new Item" window didnt have a section for "Cross Platform", so Im currently unable to add Xaml to any new project.

[image]

Ive tried to update the Xamarin.Forms NuGet Package but it didnt seem to help.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks